# Why isn't DigiSpark automatically recognized on other computers?

Tags: digispark

I bought a DigiSpark (it is a development board based on the ATtiny85 microcontroller) yesterday and I wrote my first script.

I have no problems to run it on my personal PC (which I am using to program my DigiSpark). The problem is when I try to plug my DigiSpark to another PC, which doesn't have DigiSpark drivers installed. I tried to run it on two different PCs (Windows 7) and Windows just can not find DigiSpark drivers so my script does not run.

Of course I tried to plug in to different USB ports - unfortunately it did not help.

Any ideas what can I do to make my DigiSpark run on other PC without installing drivers by myself?

Thank you.

Comment: `my script does not run`. What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean that DigiSpark is just not recognized by other PC. I have to install drivers manually first to make it working.

Comment: Make what working? What is your sketch doing that requires the PC to have the correct drivers?

Comment: Just open "CMD".

Comment: So you're running a keyboard emulation sketch, and your PC isn't recognizing it as a keyboard. So you don't really need the digispark drivers, but the keyboard "driver". Are you sure it's not being recognized? I've had similar problems, that it took too long for my PC to register it as a USB keyboard, and my code had already send the key commands. Try adding a few seconds of delay before sending the <windows>+<R> keyboard-command.

Comment: [Don't cross post](https://www.reddit.com/r/arduino/comments/5ii5mv/why_digispark_is_not_automatically_recognized_on/)

Answer (score 2):

the digi spark make use of a bitbanged usb. (emulated usb).
because of this a new pc wont see a HID keyboard but a digi spark. only when the driver is installed it will automaticly switch to the HID driver for the emulated usb stack.
they pro micro has a hardware usb stack. this wil directly show a HID keyboard and work right away.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install the drivers before you can use it on other computers.
The drivers tell a Windows PC how to talk to the device.  The device is not a generic device so Windows can't use a fall back driver, like it could with a keyboard or monitor.

Comment: So there is not any way to make it install drivers automatically right? I am suprised because I saw on YouTube that it should work.

Answer (score 1):

not true, https://www.reddit.com/r/arduino/comments/5ii5mv/why_digispark_is_not_automatically_recognized_on/
Yes, I try to get the DigiSpark to look like a keyboard to a host PC and execute a series of keystrokes. Here is my script: http://pastebin.com/dY05nbGY
permalinkembedparent
[–]cptskippy 3 points 5 months ago

Ok, you're using the DigiKeyboard library so that should make the Digispark show up as HID device. When you plug the DigiSpark into a PC where you haven't installed the drivers, does a "HID Keyboard Device" appear in the Device Manager under the Keyboards branch?

The Digispark powers up and executes the program immediately. My guess is that you probably need a delay in your code to allow the host PC to setup the interface.

```cpp
#include "DigiKeyboard.h"

void setup() {
    DigiKeyboard.delay(5000);  // Wait 5 seconds before proceeding
}

int limit = 1;
int current = 0;

void loop() {
    DigiKeyboard.update();

    if (current < limit) {
        DigiKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(0);

        DigiKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(KEY_R, MOD_GUI_LEFT);
        DigiKeyboard.delay(100);
        DigiKeyboard.println("ipconfig");
        current++;
    }

    DigiKeyboard.delay(5000);
}
```

permalinkembedparent
[–]readerpl[S] 2 points 5 months ago 
You are the best!!! IT WORKS!!!!!

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue when I first time used DigiSpark. After searching on the internet I found the solid answer that worked for me.

Arduino IDE from 1.66 to onward have not driver for DigiSpark so you have to install the driver manually when you will use Arduino IDE 1.66 or latest. But Arduino IDE 1.65 and some lower versions have support for DigiSpark.

When you will use say Arduino 1.65 and connect DigiSpark to USB port, then your PC/Laptop will automatically install the driver for DigiSpart.

Comment: did you read the question and other answers? sensai's answer explains it

Comment: Yes sensai's give the answer but I provided the answer that is not hear and it works. There maybe multiple solutions for a single problem and everyone must be discussed if you know it. That's why I shared my opinion.

Comment: but in the Question is that it is not about development computer with IDE, but about the target computer where the device is used as HID. so why do you write about IDE versions?

Comment: Sir, this is the question. "The problem is when I try to plug my DigiSpark to another PC, which doesn't have DigiSpark drivers installed. I tried to run it on two different PCs (Windows 7) and Windows just can not find DigiSpark drivers so my script does not run."

I answered it. I think now you can understand.